# Safari 7.0.4 no longer allows cross domain AJAX from the global extensions page?

Tags: safari, safari-extension

Up until a few days ago, we had a Safari extension that would hit our public API in order to fetch data about users on Twitter. While this sort of cross domain request wasn't permitted through the injected scripts, it seemed to work fine from the global HTML page, which entailed that we used the messaging system to pass data back and forth between the injected script and the global page.

This stopped working after the update to 7.0.4. The changelog indicates a whole slew of updates to address security vulnerabilities, many of which have vague descriptions. Has anyone else encountered this? What are some viable alternatives (we don't want to enable CORS on our end)?

Comment: I haven't had any trouble with cross-domain xhr from a global page after updating Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this was never answered - for whatever reason, I was indeed no longer able to do cross domain AJAX after the update. Since we were using jQuery, a simple change to have the AJAX calls use jsonp got it up and running again.